# Joining attributes in CSV by location using QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, africa

I have a shapefile which divides Africa in cells of 0.5x0.5 decimal degrees. This documents provides the longitude, latitude of the centroid of the cell and a unique identified of each cell.

On the other hand, I have a CSV file with different observations and different variables, including longitude and latitude among the variables. I transform this as a GeoPackage and they appears as a point in the QGIS.

[image]

Taking advantage of the latitude and longitude of the CSV file, I use a "Join Attributed by Location". *Input Layer:* my shp file; *Join layer:* my GeoPackage (before my CSV file); *Geometric Predicate:* I use the option "Intersects".

My main objective is to add to the grid cell the number of events of the CSV. For example, if according to the longitude and latitude of the CSV file, there are five events in a grid cell, I would like to obtain five observations in this grid cell. If I do not have any observation in one grid cell, the variables remain missing.

I do it without any problem. However, when I check the CSV that I export after doing the join, the number of observations are lower.

How is it possible? What I am doing wrong?

It should be greater than my original CSV, because it has to include all the observations of the CSV plus the grid cells that does not have any event.

I show the following picture. It is Africa divided in the grid cell and the points are the CSV. So, I would like to join the points to the grid cell. My version of QGIS is 3.20.1

This is the screen shot of my GeoPackage file (before CSV)

[image]

This is the screenshot of my shapefile:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what is the CRS?

Comment: its coordinate reference system  for each layer.

Comment: Did you use the tool "join by location (summary)" ?
With that tool you can choose the field to summarize (here: "number of events") and then you can choose the "summaries to calculate" (here: sum).

Comment: @LM10 Thank you for your answer. How can I check if they have the same coordinate reference system?

Comment: @wanderzen Thank you for your comment. I am using the tool without the summary. Is it make any change using the summary one?

Comment: you can check CRS in layer properties (informations) .

Comment: In my shp file, the CRS is: EPSG: 4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic. In the csv (the geopacke) it is empty but in the SRC appears EPSG: 4326 - WGS 84. It should be fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested and it works with `Join Attributes by Location`. See screenshot below. Important part is `Join type` and don't tick `Discard records which could not be joined`.

Result is a grid with information from point layer. If there are more points in one grid cell, resulting layer will contain  multiple copies of that feature.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Trnovstyle. I have checked and what you are suggesting it's exactly what I usually do.

Comment: Does it produce the result that you wanted?

Comment: It's produce the result I want but some observations are missing and I do not understand why.

Comment: @OgeiD So maybe you should share your data

Answer (score 6):

I guess you should use the tool ["Join attributes by location (summary)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location-summary).

Here is a picture explaining quickly how you should proceed:

[image]

***Differences between "join by location (summary)" and "join by location":***

[image]

Comment: Thank you @wanderzen . I will do it. However, can you say to me, what is the difference between both and why the join attributes that I were using does not work and this yes?

Comment: You're very welcome @OgeiD ! I've just added a picture explaining the differences between the 2 tools in my answer :)

Comment: Thank you wanderzen. I appreciate you help because this is important for me. From what I see, both are identical with the exception that the summary one creates a statistical summary. However, I do not see how this solve my problem in which my new output has fewer observations than the original one.

Comment: Could you add a sceenshot of the attribute tables of both of your layers (grid and points) ? It would help us to better understand your issue

Comment: I have added in the first comment.

Comment: I thought you had a field in which there was (for each point) some informations about the number of events (for instance: (first point = 6 events ; second points = 13 events etc...). If you just want to calculate the number of points within your grid cell you shall select "fid" in "field to summarize" then "count" in "summaries to calculate" (or you could also use @simo 's answer).

Comment: if it's not what you're trying to achieve try to better explain the issue you are facing :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer wanderzen. Yes, I have that, for each point the number of events. My problem is that in my original csv, I have 198.095 observations. When I do the join with the shapefile and I export the excel I have 192.629 observations. How is it possible? Why that 5.466 observations are missing? My points is that in the result output, I should have more than 192.629 observations. I should have that observations plus the one of the grid cell that does not match with the join layer. I hope this be clearer now.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to know the number of observations by cell, an alternative would be to use `Count points in polygon`. This will create a new temporary layer with attributes NUMPOINTS having numbers of observations by cells.

Polygon layer : `my shp file`
Points : `my geopackage (resulting from csv)`

[image: Count points in polygon image]

Comment: Thank you @simo for your help. It's not that I am interested in knowing the number of observations. It's just that I do not understand why my output has lower observations than my original file. I do not need to know the total number of observations (I am interested but it's a secondary thing) once I understand if I am doing something wrong.  Do you understand my problem? I really need help on it because I am a bit lost

Comment: @OgeiD : got it ! But what's happening when you count observations using that technique ? do you have less or do you have the right count ? Testing it could be a way to solve / understand your issue.

Comment: Thank you. I do but I am not sure how to check the total number of points. I go layer properties (information) and it appears 12.431 objects, but these are the numer of cells. And each cell has different observations. How can I count all the observations?

Comment: Select the resulting layer and open Attributes tables (right click), then check value of NUMPOINTS column for each cell

Comment: But do I have to go cell by cell summing then or there is a way to sum the NUMPOINTS of every cell directly?

Comment: Just execute the algorithm as explained in my Answer (see also screenshot). It will do it for every single cell contained in your polygon layer

Comment: Yes, I did it and I obtained the number of numpoints for each grid cell. But my point is, how can I know the total number of NUMPOINTS? I go to Attributes table and for each cell I see the total number of points. However, I cannot know if this is correct or not, I can check the total number of points in total comparing with the observations of my original csv, but I cannot check cell by cell.

Comment: @OgeiD: if you are not familiar with QGIS just copy and paste the attribute table containing the number of numpoints for each grid cell and calculate the sum of this column in excel

Comment: I sum all the NUMPOINTS in excel and I obtained 183.808 observations. Lower observations than in my original one. It's like it's not doing the matching well and I do not understand why.

Comment: @OgeiD : and what is the total of points (observations) on your geopackage file ? you can right-click the layer and click "Show feature count" or use stats panel to know it https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#statistical-summary-panel

Comment: 197.661. That it is a bit lower than my excel file, 198.095. So, some observations are also missing when I transform the GeoPackage. Mmm...

Comment: Some of the observations are probably outside cells ...